# Using Timer0 overflow to gate Timer1 on PIC12F1822

Tags: pic, microchip, timer

I am trying to use `TMR1` to count `TMR0` overflows. To do this I am using `TMR1` with gate enabled, and using `TMR0` overflow as the gate source.

Using MPLAB SIM, I can see that `TMR0` is counting and overflowing. The `TMROIF` bit in `INTCON` is being set correctly.

`TMR1` counts correctly without the gate enabled, and stops when I enable the gate control - so far so good.

However, `TMR0` overflowing does not seem to be triggering the gate. The `T1GVAL` bit of `T1GCON` is never set.

I am running `TMR1` at Fosc and I have the gate running *not* in toggle mode or single pulse mode...
`TMR0` is running at `instruction clock / 256`, although I presume that this doesn't matter...

Here are my config bits:

```
__CONFIG _CONFIG1, _FOSC_INTOSC & _WDTE_OFF & _PWRTE_OFF & _MCLRE_ON & _CP_OFF & _CPD_OFF & _BOREN_OFF & _CLKOUTEN_OFF & _IESO_OFF & _FCMEN_OFF</code>
__CONFIG _CONFIG2, _WRT_OFF & _PLLEN_OFF & _STVREN_OFF & _BORV_19 & _LVP_OFF
```

and here are the relevant lines where I configure `TMR1`

```
banksel T1CON
movlw   b'01000001' ; source = Fosc, prescale 1:1, LP osc - no, Timer on
movwf   T1CON

banksel T1GCON
movlw   b'11000001' ; gate enabled, active high, toggle no, pulse mode no, source TMR0
movwf   T1GCON
```

Comment: Step back and think of the real problem.  You can count timer 0 overflows in software, which can then use any RAM bytes it wants as the counter.  I don't see a reason that timer 1 needs to do the counting, especially since it is awkward.  You are letting one implementation idea drive the design.  It should be the other way around.  What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Touché, Olin ;) Sage advice, and I have done this.

I still want to know why it didn't work the way I was trying though...

Perhaps I should rephrase my question... What is this feature for if not something like this? It still seems the more elegant solution...

Comment: What is *what* feature for?

Comment: The ability to use Timer0 overflow as the Gate for Timer1...

Comment: The uses are only limited by your imagination.  I don't know why the designers added it, but that doesn't matter anyway since it is here.  The first thing I thought of was a frequency counter application.  Timer 0 is used to open the gate of timer 1 for a known time.  The counts accumulated on timer 1 during that time is then proportional to frequency.

Comment: Indeed you could do that (although equally it too could be done in software), but it would still rely on getting the damn thing to actually work ;)

On this matter, I think we are still no closer to a resolution...

Comment: Even though this doesn't help your issue: the [data sheet of the PIC12F1822](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41413C.pdf) explains (in part 27.6) that this mode can be used for capacitive sensors(where one need to detect changes in frequency).

Comment: Things to check/try: do you use any other peripherals which might interfere with any of the timers (e.g. ADC, CCP)? Can you enable the gate toggle mode - this will prolong the overflow impulse - maybe it is just one clock period (though I doubt this). ALso, you can try to copy the state of the T1GVAL flag to some output pin, to observe what happens (maybe by using an interrupt triggered by the gate). Maybe this helps to see whats wrong.

Comment: Can you post the code that configures TMR0?

Comment: Also, are you running this in hardware or MPLAB SIM?

Comment: @Camil I see that you set up the bounty, but the OP has not signed in since Oct 9, 2012.  This makes it a little difficult to resolve.

Comment: I am simulating this and experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 8):

I think your problem is based on confusion over exactly what the TMR1 Gate signal actually does. It does not, by itself, *cause* the timer to count, it merely *enables* it to count if there are suitable events occurring on its clock input.

It's subtle, but if you look at "FIGURE 21-1: TIMER1 BLOCK DIAGRAM" in the datasheet (p. 179), you'll see the TMR1H/TMR1L register in the middle. All of the logic above that is related to gating, and all of the logic below that is related to clocking. It all comes together at the flip-flop just to the right of the TMR1 register, where the gate signal drives the EN (enable) input of that flip-flop, and the clock signal drives the D (data) input.

What this means is that the output of the flip-flop will toggle (and cause TMR1 to increment) only if the gate signal is high **and** the clock signal is toggling.

There simply is no way to route overflow events from TMR0 to the *clock* logic of TMR1, either inside or outside the chip.

EDIT: OK, digging a little deeper (prompted by the comments below), I notice that you have the T1SYNC bit in the T1CON register set to zero. This causes the clock source to be synchronized to Fosc. If that clock source is in fact Fosc itself, the output of the synchronizer will be a constant level — always high or always low, but not toggling.

I believe *this* is the root cause of your problem. Try setting T1CON to `b'01000101'`. This should accomplish what you want, assuming that the overflow pulse from TMR0 is exactly one Fosc period long.

Comment: Right, I see what you mean and think it is right! I will however wait with the bounty until other people can have responded as well.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.  The gate logic should get a pulse with the same duration as one TMR1 clock period (via a tacit pulse synchronizer) when TMR0 oveflows, and the clock logic gets a clock.  It should count once at every overflow.  So, why would it not work?  Perhaps the simulator just fails at it (it is notoriously lacking when simulating peripherals).  The OP never said he tried it in hardware.

Comment: @apalopohapa: No, the clock logic does *not* get a clock. That's the missing piece here.

Comment: Ok, lets step back a little.  The core of TMR1 is a counter.  This counter always counts as long as it gets a clock... (continued on next comment)

Comment: This clock is provided by a D flip-flop.  This FF has three inputs: (1) *Enable*, (2) *Data*, and HAS to be clocked by the (3) *system clock* (otherwise the TMR1 would not work at all).  *Enable* comes from the gate logic. *D* comes from the clock logic.  An overflow pulse goes into the gate logic, and ends up at the *Enable* input.  A clock, FOSC, routes via muxes into the *D* input.  I see nothing that prevents FOSC (or any other selectable clock source) from reaching the *D* input, therefore making the counter count whenever *Enable* is asserted.

Comment: In other words, a TMR0 overflow event sends a pulse to the *Enable* input, allowing TMR1 to count once.

Comment: Internally this pulse should be synchronized or long enough so that it catches the high of the *D* input once.

Comment: @apalopohapa: OK, I see your point. I've modified my answer above.

Comment: This works like a charm! Thanks Dave Tweed and @apalopohapa!